# Returning a value of a span tag using selenium.webdriver.find_element_by_xpath()

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the current video time from a youtube video as it is playing.

I've inspected the youtube page to find the element where the current time value is stored. This is the element below.

```
span class="ytp-time-current">0:03</span>
```

I had to remove the strict inequality signs before and after span because it returns 0:03 and the entire tag can't be seen.

I've tried searching finding the value using `wd.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-time-current") but returns none`

I've also copied the xpath for the element:

```
//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[20]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[1]
```

and tried finding the value using the _xpath( )

## code I've tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'pathtodriver')
wd.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N__fRbG84fI')

search = wd.find_element_by_class_name('ytp-time-current') 

value = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[22]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[1]').get_attribute('Value')
```

I expected to get an integer value or at least a string. but both scenarios return none.

Answer (score 0):

A `<span>` tag doesn't have a value attribute.  You probably want to do:

```
value = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[22]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[1]').text
```

(I'm assuming this is the Python bindings)